# How will Hello Wallet benefit me? Is it worth the cost?

Tags: united-states, online-tools

I am considering using Hello Wallet as a 9.95/month online personal finance and financial guidance tool. I like the concept and the Board of Directors and the fact that it does NOT push financial products within the software.

I was hoping to hear any comments good or bad from customers about HelloWallet before making the decision.

Answer (score 1):

[CreditKarma review](http://blog.creditkarma.com/step-by-step/personal-finance/review-hellowallet-the-latest-upstart-in-personal-finance-websites/)

I don't personally use HelloWallet, but I have also heard very good things about it. Independence from financial products is a HUGE thing in the field because so many investment advisers place the firm before the customer (c.f. Too Big To Fail), so having an independent resource is a huge benefit.